# Cannot deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY - JSON/Spring MVC

Tags: java, android, json

I wrote a simple web application that connects to my database. I have an application on android which sends a request to obtain the contents of the database.

At the beginning I used an ordinary string but quickly realized that it does not give me anything and I have to use an object of class created by hibernate

There is a code of my AsyncTask:

```
private class  DatabaseLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        TextView testText;
        TacticsEntity content = new TacticsEntity();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            content = restTemplate.getForObject("http://192.168.0.105:8080/SpringMVCApp/api/tactics", TacticsEntity.class);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    testText.setText(content.getId());
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when I run my app I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.jarek.stratcaller.TacticsEntity out of START_ARRAY token
            at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource@2325082d).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.jarek.stratcaller.TacticsEntity out of START_ARRAY token
            at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource@2325082d).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 1]
            at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:182)
            at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:174)
            at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:89)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:544)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.MainMenuActivity$DatabaseLoaderTask.doInBackground(MainMenuActivity.java:31)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.MainMenuActivity$DatabaseLoaderTask.doInBackground(MainMenuActivity.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.example.jarek.stratcaller.TacticsEntity out of START_ARRAY token
            at [Source: buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource@2325082d).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 1]
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:854)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:850)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1258)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:155)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:134)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2798)
            at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:179)
            at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:174)
            at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:89)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:544)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.MainMenuActivity$DatabaseLoaderTask.doInBackground(MainMenuActivity.java:31)
            at com.example.jarek.stratcaller.MainMenuActivity$DatabaseLoaderTask.doInBackground(MainMenuActivity.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

It seems to me that this might be due to the fact that my Web application returns an array:

```
  @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/tactics", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public Object[] listTacticsJson(ModelMap model) throws JSONException {
        return tacticsRepository.findAll().toArray();
    }
```

TacticsRepository class:

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TacticsRepository extends JpaRepository<TacticsEntity, Long> {
}
```

Any ideas how to fix that?